# Why "this" argument in jQuery returns href with anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this for exemple:

```
<div id="example">
    <a href="http://www.google.com/#1">Hello</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/#4">Hello</a>
</div>
```

And this two line of jQuery:

```
jQuery("a").filter(function() {
    console.log(""+this+"")
});
```

Returns:

```
 http://www.google.com/#1

 http://www.google.com/#4
```

But

```
jQuery("a").filter(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Returns

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/#1">Hello</a>​

<a href="http://www.google.com/#4">Hello</a>​
```

Why the line 2, return the HREF attribute of the anchor IF 'this' argument add a "string"?
The jQuery docs says if filter have an function argument, the `"this" is the current DOM element`

Comment: When you say, "Returns", do you mean that that's what you see in the browser console from the `console.log()` calls? (I think it is what you mean ... )

Comment: Have you put those 2 results the wrong way round? ""+this+"" should return the value of href - http://jsfiddle.net/9muyj/

Comment: Yes, results are inverted.

Comment: I fixed the question so that the results are correctly linked to their causes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`""+this` is equivalent to `this.toString()`. On an `a` element it returns the `href` (yes, that's weird, and probably for compatibility with something that was useful a long time ago, but that's what it does on all browsers).

In the second case, you're not calling `toString` but the browser dependent console formatting method. Different choices were made : on Chrome for example it usually returns the outer html (as a browsable tree if it's big).

Comment: Is there a spec for returning the `href`? When starting to write my answer (which I then abandoned in favor of yours), I wanted to say that it was implementation-dependent as well - but I'm not sure.

Comment: I found no spec but it's kind of a (little) known fact and it's apparently universal. The old reason is probably laughable and I'd like to know it...

Comment: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element "stringifier" is the href, and the target if it doesn't exist.